# QML header id нет доступа

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
import Game 1.0

GridView {

    id: root
    model: GameboardModel {    
    }

    header: Rectangle {
        id: headerId
        color: "lightgreen"
        height: 50
        Text {
            text: "header"
            color:"blue"
        }
    }

    cellHeight: (height-headerId.height)/root.model.dimension
    cellWidth: width/root.model.dimension
    delegate: Item {
        id: bgDelegate
        width: root.cellWidth
        height: root.cellHeight
        visible: display !== root.model.hiddenElementValue
        Tile{
        anchors.fill: bgDelegate
        anchors.margins: 5
        displayText: display
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
               root.model.move(index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

есть такой файл, как обратиться к высоте хедера вне хедера(headerId.height не работает)?

размер окна 640 на 530, 50 выделено под высоту хедера. Пытаюсь через свойства обратится к высоте и полкчается следующий результат

[[image: link]]

Но если записать так cellHeight: (height-50)/root.model.dimension

все корректно отображается

[[image: link]]

но при этом цвет хедера белый, а не такой как в свойствах

Comment: Не работает - это наверное потому-что слишком далеко пытаетесь обратиться. 

Попробуйте сделать два свойства (property) - одно для цвета, другое для высоты, забиндить цвет и высоту шапки на эти свойства, а сами свойства потом править хоть откуда, цвет и высота на них забинжены и автоматически изменятся

Comment: А ещё лучше расскажите чего хотите добиться